# Show that for $a,b>0$ and $a \ne b$ and $ n > 1$ we have that $a^n-b^n < n(a-b)a^{n-1}$

Tags: inequality

Show that for $a,b>0$ and $a \ne b$ and $ n > 1$ we have that:

$$a^n-b^n < n(a-b)a^{n-1}$$

---

For $1 \le k \le n-1$ : $$a^{n-1-k}b^k < a^{n-1}$$ $$\iff b^k <a^k$$ $$\iff a <b$$

And for $k=0$ the equality happens.
And so :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}b^{k}<na^{n-1}$$

$$\left(a-b\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}b^{k}<n\left(a-b\right)a^{n-1}$$
$$a^{n}-b^{n}<n\left(a-b\right)a^{n-1}$$

I think the relation only holds if $a <b$ ,am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^n$ and $a>b$, $n>1$ Let us apply LMVT to f(x) in $(b,a)$, then

$$\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=nc^{n-1}, c\in (b,a)~~~~(1)$$
next $$ b<c<a \implies c^{n-1}< a^{n-1}~~~~(2)$$
Combining (1) and (2), we get
$$a^n-b^n< n(a-b)a^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Yes, very much because I have assumed $a>b$ in the beginning ,actually the other result that can follow is $a^n-b^n> n b^{n-1}.$

Comment: We have proved that when $a>b$ the given inequality holds, then our attempt to find any example otherwise will fail only.